# SwiftUI: Delay when tap on NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have the following setup:

**CustomCell.swift**

```
struct CustomCell: View {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    
    init(title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
            Spacer()
            Text(subtitle)
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenView.swift**

```
struct ScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("message")) {
                        CustomCell(title: "cellTitle", subtitle: "cellSubtitle")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("message")) {
                        CustomCell(title: "cellTitle", subtitle: "cellSubtitle")
                    }
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .listStyle(.automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabIndex = 0
   
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
            Text("Empty screen")
                .onTapGesture {
                    tabIndex = 0
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("First", systemImage: "circle.fill")
                }
                .tag(0)
            ScreenView()
                .onTapGesture {
                    tabIndex = 1
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "square.fill")
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
        .tint(.red)
        .onAppear() {
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .lightGray
        }
    }
}
```

When I tap on a row it seems that my tap it's not recognized and nothing happens.
I have to long tap in order to push the new screen instead.

Is there anything I can do in order to achieve the normal behavior?

Comment: cannot replicated your issue, all works well for me in my tests,
 on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
 It could be different on older systems. Why do you have 3 times the same `CustomCell`,
 is this really what you have in your real code?

Comment: there was a mistake, I have edited the code

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, I have updated the source code by adding the tab bar that I use. Please give it a try, the issue should be reproducible

Comment: There is no need for that onTapGesture for each tab. If you are using a tutorial you should let the author know this has been asked on SO several times lately

Comment: yes,  just remove the `.onTapGesture { tabIndex = 0 }`, same for `tabIndex = 1`.
 The `TabView(selection: $tabIndex)`, already takes care of this.